# Is there a way to locate a java file quickly and directly in Eclipse if I know its filename?

Tags: java, eclipse

For example, I know I have a java file named "HelloWorld.java". I don't like to browse the package hierarchy to find it finally. I'd like there is a way that let me input this filename and open it directly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`CTRL + SHIFT + T` for classes (.java files represent classes), and `CTRL + SHIFT + R` for all files.

A dialog will open where you can type the name of the class/file. Note that you can also use wildcards (`*, ?`) and camel case starting letters. For example, if you type `HW`, `HelloWorld` will be located.

Answer (score 4):

`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`R` will give you an auto-complete panel.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, just type Ctrl-Shift-R to find resources, meaning all files in your project.